# cyclic coordinate descent

Tags: optimization

is it possible to implement cyclic coordinate descent to numerically solve optimization problem with equality constraints like:
$$\mathrm{min} \quad f(x)$$
$$a^\top x=b$$
Suppose f(x): $\mathrm{R}^n\to \mathrm{R}$ convex and it is not hard to update $x_i$ when $x_j$, $j \neq i$ fixed, how to satisfy the equality constraint to achieve feasibility?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe the problem is still easy after using $a^Tx=b$ to substitute out one variable.

Comment: thanks@LinAlg. um.. can you elaborate your idea a bit more?

Comment: If $a^Tx = b$ is $x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 5$, you can write $x_1 = 5-2x_2-x_3$ to get rid of $x_1$ in the objective function.

Comment: Presumably that might negate the "ease" of the coordinate descent. Really curious about the context of the problem.